# The meaning of "stands for a portrait"

Tags: meaning, phrases

> [Gregory Porter **stands for** **a portrait** at the North Sea Jazz Festival in
>   Rotterdam, Netherlands on July 6, 2012](http://www.newsweek.com/2015/10/09/rb-singer-gregory-porter-may-make-jazz-relevant-new-generation-377010.html).

I'm struggling with this sentence. What does 'stand for a portrait' mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As this is about images, I thought illustration would be an excellent method of explanation.

Here is someone who is photographed when they **stand for a portrait**:

[image: http://www.sky.com/tv/show/portrait/gallery/artists-at-work-cardiff]

By comparison, here is someone who is photographed when they **sit for an artist**:

[image]

So: the person is in the standing posture in an artists studio while having their portrait painted. It can also apply to having a photographic portrait made in a studio<sup>*</sup>.

<sup>*</sup><sub>I'm having trouble explaining in any more detail the language elements here...</sub>

Comment: +1 You're having no trouble at all; this is admirably clear.